# Detect end of new message in email conversation body

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

When a message gets replied or forwared the previous thread gets appended on your new mail by placing i.e. ----Original Message---- in front of it.

Outlook does the same with tekst messages but with HTML mails it shows a line followed with From:..

Since outlook shows a line in between these messages i believe it's possible to subtract these messages using VBA. But How?

Goal: When the user sends a mail (Application_ItemSend) I want to scan the message for certain words. But I don't care if it occurs in a previous message, i only want to scan the newly typed message.

The example below will work when answering an email in outlook when it's in text (and outlook is in english!). But it will NOT work when sending a HTML email.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim EndOfMsg As Integer
  Dim myMsg as String

  EndOfMsg = InStr(Item.Body, "-----Original Message-----")
  If EndOfMsg = 0 Then 
    myMsg = Item.Body
  Else 
    myMsg = Left(Item.Body, EndOfMsg)
  End If

  MsgBox myMsg
End Sub
```

So i need some 'token' to split on, correct.. But what is this token? All there is between myMsg and the older msg's is a double `vbCrLf`. The same as when i enter a new line in my message.. no nothing at all unique!

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your existing code you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Use `Split` to tokenize the message body based on the delimiter yo are looking for; the first element (element zero) is the text before it, the second element (element one) is the text after it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on whether the user is sending HTML or rich text email. (This will usually depend on whether they are replying to/forwarding a message in HTML or RTF, unless they manually change the format.)

In either case, you need to look for a pattern that indicates the end of the message you are interested in, and stop there. Use `Instr()` to identify where you need to stop. Then, as you are parsing the text looking for your "certain words", keep track of how many characters you have read and stop when you get to the marker.

**Rich text**

Look in `Item.Body` for "^p^p_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** ^p".

That's 2 instances of VbCrLf, 46 instances of Chr(95), a space, and then another instance of VbCrLf.

**HTML**

In `Item.Body`, the token is "^p  **_**  ^p".

That's one VbCrLf, 2 spaces, 5 instances of Chr(95), 2 more spaces, and another VbCrLf.

In `Item.HTMLBody`, the token is

```
<DIV dir=ltr lang=en-us class=OutlookMessageHeader align=left>
<HR tabIndex=-1>
```

That token has a VbCrLf before it, between the two lines, and at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your input but i could not find any Chr(95) in my myMail.Body nor myMailHTMLBody..

Comment: I have just used OutlookSpy to browse all the properties of this MailItem.. but i cannot find any pattern in the Body nor HTMLBody property. Nor can I find any clue on what else to use :-(

Comment: Ah, you're sending HTML mail, I'm sending rich text mail. In HTML mail, you should be looking for either "`_____`" in the Item.Body or "`<HR tabIndex=-1>`" in Item.HTMLBody

Comment: Could you post a sample of your `Item.Body` and `Item.HTMLBody`? Then I could be more helpful. At the moment I am testing using my computer, but my configuration might be different to yours.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an array of messages as below:

```
Dim arr() As String

arr() = Split(Item.Body, "From:")
```

Then loop through the messages:

```
Dim varElement as variant

for each varElement in arr()

next varElement
```

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your `InStr` function to `EndOfMsg = InStr(1, Item.Body, "From:")`?