# Is there such thing as Outlook Message Delimiter?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have **one** mailitem that contains lots of messages exchanged (a message with a large historic, if you will).

Within the `Msg.Body` ,I need to know where a message begins and where it ends. I have been using `From:` but it is not accurate.

Is there a method to split one mail body into an array containing one message per item ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768756/detect-end-of-new-message-in-email-conversation-body

Answer (score 1):

No, you need parse the message body text in the code. There is no explicit indicators.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.