# How to get only one selected mail using VBA (Outlook)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems()
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
 Dim mySender As Outlook.AddressEntry
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
 Dim strSenderID As String
 Const PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID As String = _
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102"
 Dim MsgTxt As String
 Dim x As Long

 MsgTxt = ""
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
 If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then
 ' For mail item, use the SenderName property.
 Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x)
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.Body

 ElseIf myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then
 ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property.
 Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x)
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oAppt.Organizer & ";"
 Else
 ' For other items, use the property accessor to get sender ID,
 ' then get the address entry to display the sender name.
 Set oPA = myOlSel.Item(x).PropertyAccessor
 strSenderID = oPA.GetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID)
 Set mySender = Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(strSenderID)
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & mySender.Name & ";"
 End If
 Next x
 Debug.Print MsgTxt
End Sub
```

When I run this code, I will get body of selected mail. But I get mail with ALL branch in current selected mail. So, I want to get only one selected mail, without branch.

How to do this?

Comment: if there are multiple selected mails, which one should be selected?

Comment: If you want the last text added see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300361/copy-to-clipboard-only-the-most-recent-reply-in-a-conversation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768756/detect-end-of-new-message-in-email-conversation-body

Answer (score 0):

There is only one message body. It is not separated into separate parts created during the reply/forward exchange. It is your responsibility to parse the body text.